# Is strcpy equivalent to strcpy_s

Tags: c++, msdn, c-strings, null-terminated, string.h

I would like to know if I can safely replace strcpy_s defined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx - (the one with two arguments) with strcpy defined here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy - (the first one). If no then what is the closest version of *strcpy* that I can use to replace strcpy_s?

Comment: Well `strcpy_s` does include one additional parameter you can screw up

Comment: What is your goal here? You certainly can but generally shouldn't replace `strcpy_s` with a `strcpy` if you don't know why it was there in the first place.

Comment: Can you? Yes. Can you do so safely? Well, considering that you're replacing a more secure function with a less secure one, I'd say no.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `std::string` and avoiding the entire issue?

Comment: They're not equivalent. `strcpy_s` is designed to abort your process by default if the target buffer is breached and a buffer overflow ensues So can you replace it back to native standard C `strcpy` ? Sure. Will it be as-safe or safer? No.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious:  The regular overload of strcpy_s has an extra parameters, but the template version does not.  You can use the template version when the number of elements in the destination can be deduced.

Answer (score 4):

The C11 standard added [bounds-checked functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error#Bounds_checking) including [`strcpy_s()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). So if you're worried about portability, it's okay as long as you have a C11-compliant compiler. Note that C11-standard "constraint handler" is slightly different than the Microsoft CRT's "invalid parameter handler" so if you're installing a custom handler, it may need some adjustments.

As for replacing it altogether, no, you can't safely replace it with `strcpy()` for reasons that should be obvious: `strcpy()` is not bounds-checked. You would either need to do your own bounds checking using `strlen()`, or use `strncpy()`, **but note that `strncpy()` behaves differently** (specifically, if the source string is too big to fit in the destination, the destination buffer will not be null-terminated).